# Apple mach-o Linker Error in Quickblox

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, linker-errors, quickblox

im new to Xcode,
I am using the Q-Municate source code to create a messaging app, but when I compile the app, it comes up with a ton of errors (57), and I cant find any working fixes. 
The issues are attached below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_WebRtcAec_InitAec_SSE2", referenced from:
      _WebRtcAec_InitAec in Quickblox(audio_processing.aec_core.o)
  "webrtc::SincResampler::Convolve_SSE(float const*, float const*, float const*, double)", referenced from:
      webrtc::SincResampler::Resample(int, float*) in Quickblox(common_audio.sinc_resampler.o)
  "webrtc::VPMContentAnalysis::TemporalDiffMetric_SSE2()", referenced from:
      webrtc::VPMContentAnalysis::VPMContentAnalysis(bool) in Quickblox(video_processing.content_analysis.o)
  "webrtc::VPMContentAnalysis::ComputeSpatialMetrics_SSE2()", referenced from:
      webrtc::VPMContentAnalysis::VPMContentAnalysis(bool) in Quickblox(video_processing.content_analysis.o)
  "_aec_rdft_init_sse2", referenced from:
      _aec_rdft_init in Quickblox(audio_processing.aec_rdft.o)
  "_vp8_build_intra_predictors_mbuv_s_sse2", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_build_intra_predictors_mbuv_s_ssse3", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_build_intra_predictors_mby_s_sse2", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_build_intra_predictors_mby_s_ssse3", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_denoiser_filter_sse2", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_dequant_idct_add_uv_block_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_dequant_idct_add_uv_block_sse2", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_dequant_idct_add_y_block_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_dequant_idct_add_y_block_sse2", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_dequantize_b_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_fast_quantize_b_sse2", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_mbblock_error_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vp8_mbblock_error_mmx_impl)
  "_vp8_mbblock_error_xmm", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vp8_mbblock_error_xmm_impl)
  "_vp8_mbuverror_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vp8_mbuverror_mmx_impl)
  "_vp8_mbuverror_xmm", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vp8_mbuverror_xmm_impl)
  "_vp8_mse16x16_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_mse16x16_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_regular_quantize_b_sse2", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_short_fdct8x4_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_mse16x16_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_mse16x16_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance16x16_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance16x16_ssse3", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance16x16_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance16x8_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance16x8_ssse3", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance16x8_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance4x4_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance4x4_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance8x16_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance8x16_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance8x8_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_sub_pixel_variance8x8_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_subtract_b_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vp8_subtract_b_mmx_impl)
  "_vp8_subtract_b_sse2", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vp8_subtract_b_sse2_impl)
  "_vp8_variance16x16_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance16x16_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance16x8_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance16x8_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance4x4_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance4x4_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance8x16_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance8x16_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance8x8_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance8x8_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance_halfpixvar16x16_h_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance_halfpixvar16x16_h_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance_halfpixvar16x16_hv_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance_halfpixvar16x16_hv_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance_halfpixvar16x16_v_mmx", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
  "_vp8_variance_halfpixvar16x16_v_wmt", referenced from:
      _setup_rtcd_internal in Quickblox(libvpx.rtcd.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help with the issue would be great!

Comment: It seems like the library you are using is not compiled for simulator use. What happens if you build on a device?

Comment: Yeah, try to use a real device. Qmunicate uses WebRTC for video chat, it doesn't work on simulator

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all require dependency

CFNetwork, SystemConfiguration, MobileCoreServices, CoreGraphics, CoreLocation, CoreData, AudioToolbox, CoreMedia, Accelerate, CoreVideo, AVFoundation, Security, libz, libresolv, libxml or libxml2 frameworks

Answer (score 0):

This means that your has not been linked properly, go in your targets>build Phases and Check if you have the QuickBlox framework listed there, If You do , then you may need to check your FrameWork Search PAth if the path to your framework file is appropriate

Comment: My quickblox framework is in the link binary with libraries part of build phases, the search path is correct too...

Comment: then there must be a "lib" library, which is missing try going through quiqblox framework installation again, there must be some clue there

Comment: After getting a new copy of the framework, it seems to get rid of those errors. Thanks!